# wrapping sections with HTML tags in vim

Tags: html, vim, plugins

I want to be able to quickly wrap entire sections of my HTML with other tags. I run into this a lot when I realize I need an outer div around my other divs, like so:

**Original HTML:**

```
<div id='a'>
   <img src='a.png'>
</div>
<div id='b'>
   <img src='b.png'>
</div>
```

**Modified HTML:**

```
<div id='Main'>
   <div id='a'>
      <img src='a.png'>
   </div>
   <div id='b'>
      <img src='b.png'>
   </div>
</div>
```

I could use [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) and [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) but I don't believe surround.vim surrounds with words (ie. `<div>`), just single characters (ie. `<`) and it also does not indent.

The closest thing I can think of right now takes 15-20 button presses.

Comment: surround.vim does indeed support this.  It's right there in the readme but vim.org seems to mangle it.  See here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: @RandyMorris I know it surrounds with HTML tags. But README states it also indents inner text, how can it be achieved?

Comment: Using `S` instead of `s` I believe.

Comment: Yes, use `S` for clean indented HTML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`surround.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) can surround with html tags, but it <s>does not indent</s> indents only when using `S` from visual mode, not `ys` and not `s` in visual, thanks to @RandyMorris. It also putts same-indented div’s on the next and previous lines (without indenting) if the motion to `ys` or visual selection used was linewise. Does not do even this for `yss`, so you have to use `ysg@<div>j>>` if you really want to avoid visual mode.

**Update**: there are `g:surround_indent` and `b:surround_indent` options. If you set any of them surround.vim will use `=` to indent surrounded text with its surroundings and the above mess with `ys` not indenting will be false, as well as `S` (`S` will use `=` as well). Requires `filetype indent on` and proper indenting settings.

If you don’t set these options you will see behavior described in the first paragraph: `S` indents unconditionally.

Comment: I use surround.vim and it surrounds with tags and indents properly. I also have 'indent on' and 'set autoindent' in my vimrc.

Comment: @GaryWilloughby I'll accept this answer if you mention how indentation is incorporated, or maybed Gary could shed light on this.

Comment: @puk select lines using line select mode ('V') then hit capital 'S'. This allows you to enter a tag on the command line, when the tag is closed surround surrounds and indents the selected lines.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, surround is indeed the way to go. Supposing your cursor is on the first `div`:

```
V%j%S<div id="Main"<CR>
```

or

```
V5jS<div id="Main"<CR>
```

do the trick.

Depending on the context, the whole thing could even be shortened to:

```
Vat<div id="Main"<CR>
```

The `<div id="Main"` part seems hard to skip.

There are other ways, of course.

ZenCoding, for example lets you use CSS syntax like that:

```
V5j<C-y>,div#Main<CR>
```

I am not aware of any faster way to get what you want.

TextMate's <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> was nice, that's for sure, but it defaulted to `<p>` so you'd have to type `div id="Main"` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

place cursor at tag you want to surround with,

`vatS<div id="Main"><CR>`

Comment: but after vat+"S" not possible type tag - only the first symbol writing. Only after vat+"St" you may write tag name

Answer (score 1):

1. Visually select the tag you want to surround with
2. press `St`
3. In the command line, a prompt will appear, typically saying something like:
   `Enter the HTML tag:`
4. Enter the desired tag, and it will enclose the highlighted content with the specified tag.